# Tensorboard can't display two runs at the same time?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

When I run the LSTM model with tensorboard to watch on the loss, I encountered a problem. I now described what I have done:

1. I first ran a model(named model1) and saved events file into
   'log/model1', and then I stopped running.
2. And then I adjusted hyper parameters to run the second model(named model2). I saved event files for model2 into directory of 'log/model2'.
3. This time I started tensorboard by command: 'tensorboard --logdir=log', at the same time the model2 was still running.

Problems:

On tensorboard website I found there were indeed two models in 'runs' diretory in the left corner named model1 and model2 respectively. But I can **only see pictures for model1 in dashboard**.

I selected the button before 'model2' and deselected the one before 'model1' and **there was nothing displayed.** I changed the 'Horizontal Axis' into 'WALL'(I don't know what it means but I found the horizontal axis is a time line.) and found that the time for model2 is 1970.

And I still found that when I switch to model1,  it updated every 30 seconds but I have stopped the model1. Is it just a design in tensorboard?

---

I stopped model2 just now, and then the line chart for model2 appeared in dashboard, along with that for model1.

I think that I can watch on the loss at the same time when the model is running(I really can if there is only one run in tensorboard, but fail if there is more than one run).

I supposed if I write into event files too frequently? I saved event files **every 50 global steps**.

Comment: You can watch Tensorboard during training with no problem. The only thing to keep in mind is that there is a bit of a delay, so you won't see the updated results immediately. There is a refresh button on top-right that you can use. Looks like you are doing everything right, except I'd think that every 50 steps is not frequent enough. I do it every step and it's OK performance-wise. Gives you nice detailed picture of the progress and nice way to compare various runs as you adjust hyperparameters.

Comment: In fact I have tried the refresh button and nothing changed. But I think there is indeed a delay even though it seems that the delay is much longer than I think.  Still, thank U~~